# Silverlight Hardware Accelerated Graphics

Tags: silverlight, graphics, gpu, hardware-acceleration

- Is there anyway to create cross platform hardware accelerated games in Silverlight? (OpenGL binding or something similar)
- Does libraries like [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/) usable for writing large 3D games (e.g MMORPGs) in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no access to cross platform APIs like OpenGL in Silverlight, there may be some limited cross platform hardware acceleration but that is upto the specific plugin implementations for those platforms.

Nor is Silverlight an appropriate platform for large 3D games at present.